# Different between MACTripleDES and HMAC in .NET cryptography

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

As the title says, I don't really understand the difference between the two implementations of keyed hash algorithm (or, to be precise, between `MACTripleDES` and implementations of `HMAC`).

Both can `ComputeHash()` and `HashCore()`. The only differences I see is that in `MACTripleDES` you can specify which type of hash function you want to use and:

`HashCore()` of HMAC:

> Routes data written to the object into the default HMAC hash algorithm for computing the hash value.

`HashCore()` of MACTripleDES:

> Routes data written to the object into the TripleDES encryptor for computing the Message Authentication Code (MAC)

From what I know about MAC, you digest the message using keyed hash algorithm to produce MAC. So in `MACTripleDES`, you hash the message with some hashing algorithm and then encrypt it using TripleDES to produce MAC, whereas in `HMAC` you just straightly use some keyed hash algorithm on the original message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MACTripleDES` doesn't use a hash function to calculate the MAC. It uses `TripleDES` which is an encryption algorithm.

`HMAC` is an `abstract` class meaning you cannot instantiate the class itself. You have to derive from it.

Derived classes from `HMAC` internally calls `HashCore`. `HashCore` is overridden to perform a specific hash function for each derived class:

- **MD5** for HMACMD5
- **RIPEMD-160** for HMACRIPEMD160
- **SHA-1** for HMACSHA1
- **SHA-256** for HMACSHA256
- **SHA-386** for HMACSHA384
- **SHA-512** for HMACSHA512

`MACTripleDES`, derived from `KeyedHashAlgorithm`, also has a `HashCore` method but it's not the same method as in `HMAC`. This `HashCore` method is defined to specifically use `TripleDES` to calculate the MAC. Hence you cannot "specify which type of hash function you want to use".

Since `TripleDES` is not a hash function it should not, and does not, derive from `HMAC`.

**Addendum:**

According to the, now withdrawn, FIPS 113 document:

> 3 GENERATION OF THE DAC
>
> The Data Authentication Algorithm (DAA) makes use of the Data
>   Encryption Standard (DES) cryptographic algorithm specified in FIPS
>   PUB 46. The DES algorithm transforms (or encrypts) 64-bit input
>   vectors to 64-bit output vectors using a cryptographic key. Let D be
>   any 64-bit input vector and assume a key has been selected. The 64-bit
>   vector, O, which is the output of the DES algorithm when DES is
>   applied to D, using the enciphering operation, is represented as
>   follows.
>
> O = e(D)
>
> The data (e.g., record, file, message, or program) to be authenticated
>   is grouped into contiguous 64-bit blocks: D1, D2,.... Dn. If the number
>   of data bits is not a multiple of 64, then the final input block will
>   be a partial block of data, left justified. with zeroes appended to
>   form a full 64-bit block. The calculation of the DAC is given by the
>   following equations where + represents the Exclusive-OR of two
>   vectors.
>
> 01 = e(D1)
>   02 = e(D2 + 01)
>   03 = e(D3 + 02)
>   On = e(Dn + 0n-1)
>
> The DAC is selected from On. Devices which Implement the DAA shall be
>   capable of selecting the leftmost M bits of On as the DAC, where 16 <
>   M < 64 and M is a multiple of 8. A block diagram of the DAC generation
>   is given in Appendix 1 and an example is given in Appendix 2. The
>   Cipher Block Chaining Mode (CBC) with Initialization Vector (IV) = 0
>   and the 64-bit Cipher Feedback Mode with IV = D1 and data equal to D2,
>   D3, ..., Dn (see FIPS PUB 81) both yield the required DAC calculation

[image]

As you can see it's the data (in 64-bit blocks) that is encrypted using CBC mode. The MAC is the last encrypted data block truncated to between 24 and 56 bits (inclusive).

Although FIPS 113 specifies `DES` as the algorithm the same applies to `TripleDES`.

*Note:* Since `DES` and `TripleDES` are concidered insecure so is `MACTripleDES`. This is the reason FIPS 113 was withdrawn.